# Can I use a slim version of my header to be included with the library?

Tags: c++, oop

What I mean is my real header file can look like this:

```
#include "some_internal_class.h"

class MyLibrary {
    Type private_member;

    void private_function();
public:

    MyLibrary();
    void function_to_be_called_by_library_users();
};
```

Now I want to produce a dynamic library containing all the necessary definitions. and I want to ship with it a single header instead of shipping every single header I have in my library.

So I was thinking I could create a slim version of my header like so:

```
class MyLibrary {
public:     
    MyLibrary();
    void function_to_be_called_by_library_users();
};
```

Headers are just declarations anyway right? they're never passed to the compiler. And I've declared what the user will be using.

Is that possible? If not, why not?

Comment: The second definition also implies that the size of `MyLibrary' is smaller than its actual size. Even if it were allowed it would cause big problems.

Comment: "they're never passed to the compiler" -- yes they are. The compiler needs to know the members of a class so it knows its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Header are just declarations anyway right? they're never passed to the
>   compiler. And I've declared what the user will be using.

No. Headers are part of source code and are compiled together with source files. They contain the information necessary for a compiler to understand how to work with code (in your case, with class `MyLibrary`).

As an example, you want library users to be able to create objects of class `MyLibrary`, so you export the constructor. However, this is not sufficient: the compiler needs to know the *size* of the object to be created, which is impossible unless you specify all the fields.

In practice, deciding what to expose to library users and what to hide as implementation details is a hard question, which requires detailed inspection of the library usage and semantics. If you really want to hide the class internals as implementation detail, here are some common options:

- The [pimpl](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) idiom is a common solution. It enables you to work with the class as it is usually done, but the implementation details are nicely hidden.
- Extract the interface into an [abstract class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes) with virtual functions, and use pointers (preferably [smart pointers](https://www.meetingcpp.com/blog/items/an-overview-on-smart-pointers.html)) to work with the objects.

Answer (score 7):

This is a One Definition Rule violation. The moment you deviate by a single token.

[[basic.def.odr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6)

> There can be more than one definition of a class type, [...] in a
>   program provided that each definition appears in a different
>   translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following
>   requirements. Given such an entity named D defined in more than one
>   translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and

Your program may easily break if you violate the ODR like that. And your build system isn't at all obligated to even warn you about it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a class twice. It breaks the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (ODT). `MyLibrary` does that, unfortunately.

> they're never passed to the compiler

They will. Members of a class must be known at compile time, so that the compiler can determine the class's size.

Answer (score 2):

> Headers are just declarations anyway right? they're never passed to the compiler.

The moment you do a `#include` to a file, its content are copied and pasted into your source file exactly as they are.
So even though you don't pass them directly as compiler arguments, they're still part of your code and code in them will be compiled into your translation units.

Solutions by @lisyarus are pretty good.

But another option would be doing it the C way. Which is the most elegant in my opinion.

In C you give your users a handle, which will most likely be a pointer.

Your header would look something like this:

```
struct MyLibrary;

MyLibrary*
my_library_init();

void
my_library_destroy(MyLibrary*);

void
my_library_function_to_be_called_by_library_users(MyLibrary*);
```

A very small and simple interface that does not show your users anything you don't want them to see.

Another nice perk is that your build system will not have to recompile your whole program just because you added a field to the `MyLibrary` struct.

You have to watch out though, because now you have to call `my_library_destroy` which will carry the logic of your destructor.